# Nobody at the table said so[meaning here]

Tags: meaning

I read this passage in [I heard you paint houses](https://www.nytimes.com/2004/06/20/books/chapters/i-heard-you-paint-houses.html):

> The night before my testimonial dinner, Russ and I had a sit-down with Jimmy. We sat at a table at Broadway Eddie's, and Russell Bufalino told Jimmy Hoffa flat-out he should stop running for union president. He told him certain people were very happy with Frank Fitzsimmons, who replaced Jimmy when he went to jail. **Nobody at the table said so,** but we all knew these certain people were very happy with the big and easy loans they could get out of the Teamsters Pension Fund under the weak-minded Fitz.

I'm not sure what it means here.
I have seen 'say so' in dialogues like:

> A: Hey You said you were afraid of dogs, right?
>
> B: I didn't say so.

Comment: It's just a variant of << We all knew [that?] certain people were very happy with the big and easy loans they could get out of the Teamsters Pension Fund under the weak-minded Fitz ... but nobody at the table said so. / ... but nobody at the table actually voiced this thought. >> Putting the 'Nobody present actually said so (/ as much), [but everyone was thinking ... ]' clause at the front of the sentence can be a smooth style option. Care has to be taken to keep the whole sentence clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*So* refers to what follows, just like in your own example it refers to what was said earlier. The sentence could be rewritten in the following way without changing its meaning:

> Nobody at the table said that these certain people were very happy with the big and easy loans they could get out of the Teamsters Pension Fund under the weak-minded Fitz, but we all knew it.

Answer (score 0):

***"So"*** in this context has the same meaning as when Captain Picard on Star Trek says, **"Make it *so*,"**: roughly, ***thus*** or, ***thusly***.

Answer (score 0):

"Said so" is something of an idiom, meaning "said it was so". "So", in this case, is used as a [pronoun](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so) (or an [adverb](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/so), according to some authorities) meaning roughly "what is specified elsewhere in this conversation".